# Best way to compare fields in RemdeyForce and Salesforce?

Tags: community, field-mapping, id-comparison

We are migrating from RemdyForce to salesforce, and we are trying to compare and map all the fields. Is there any best way to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AutoRABIT](http://www.autorabit.com) to migrate all your Metadata from RemdyForce to Salesforce.